# Intermittent RDP Connection Issues and Desktop Icon Rearrangement

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

Hello Stack Overflow Community,

I am encountering a recurring issue with Remote Desktop Protocol (RDP) connections to my work machine. Specifically, every alternate RDP attempt fails, requiring physical intervention to resolve. This typically involves either logging in and out locally or restarting the machine.

Additionally, after resolving the connection issue, I often find that the desktop icons on the host machine are rearranged. This adds an extra layer of inconvenience as it disrupts my usual workflow.

Troubleshooting Attempts:

- Updated RDP client and host machine software - issue persists.

What steps can I take to diagnose and resolve the underlying issue?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: (1) How does the RDP fail and with what error messages? (2) Desktop icons may rearrange if the resolution changes; there exist products for saving and restoring desktop layouts, if that's a solution.